# Some question concerning curve of second order

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

Let $$F(x,y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f,$$
$$\phi(x,y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2,$$ $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.
Assume that for some $x_0, y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha^2+\beta^2>0$ the following conditions hold:
$$\phi(\alpha,\beta)=0,$$
$$\alpha(ax_0+by_0+d)+\beta(bx_0+cy_0+e)=0,$$
$$F(x_0,y_0)=0.$$

Does it follow that $$
W:=\left | \begin{array}{rrr}
a & b & d\\
b & c & e\\
d & e & f
\end{array} \right |=0 \  \ \ ?
$$

It concerns the following question from analytic geometry. 
Consider a curve $F(x,y)=0$.
Let a straight line on a plane have equations 
$$x=x_0+\alpha t,$$
$$y=y_0+\beta t,$$
where $[\alpha,\beta]$ has asymptotic direction, i.e. $\phi(\alpha,\beta)=0.$
Assume that this line lies on the curve, i.e. equation
$\phi(\alpha,\beta)t^2+2[(\alpha(ax_0+by_0+d)+\beta(bx_0+cy_0+e)]t+F(x_0,y_0)=0$ 
is satisfied by every $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the curve $F(x,y)=0$ has to be degenerated.

It is clear if we were to use the theorem about classification of curves of the second order. But I am looking for a purely algebraic explanation.

Thanks.